# How do I find which assertion failed in matlab scripts used by simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I call some matlab scripts from a simulink model, these use assert().  When an assertion fails, simulink gives me a completely useless assertion, without any details about which sub-system or script the assertion occurred in, let alone the line number:

```
An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated
Caused by:
An error occurred during simulation of Model block '<blah>/Model'.
Assertion failed.
```

However, this is just a model block, it contains many sub-systems and script blocks and stuff.

Any hints on how to find which of my many assertions was triggered?

Not sure it matters, but all of these scripts use the `%#codegen` tag.

Comment: Can you not add descriptive messages to the `assert` calls?

Comment: See also: the [`MException.last`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/capture-information-about-errors.html#bq9l5bs-1) static method or [`lasterror`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lasterror.html)

Comment: HA!  I've always used matlab asserts like "C" asserts, and honestly had never looked into if there were extra arguments such as "errmsg" .  That totally works for me!  If you write up the answer I'll take it... unless something better comes along.  :)

Comment: lasterror and MException just give me the same useless data as the dialog box, with an empty stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assert()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assert.html) supports custom error messages:

> `assert(cond,msg)` throws an error and displays the error message,
>   `msg`, if `cond` is `false`.
>
> `assert(cond,msg,A1,...,An)` displays an error message that contains
>   formatting conversion characters, such as those used with the MATLAB®
>   `sprintf` function, if `cond` is `false`. Each conversion character in
>   `msg` is converted to one of the values `A1,...,An`.
>
> `assert(cond,msgID,msg)` throws an error, displays the error message,
>   `msg`, and includes an error identifier on the exception, if `cond` is
>   `false`. The identifier enables you to distinguish errors and to
>   control what happens when MATLAB encounters the errors.
>
> `assert(cond,msgID,msg,A1,...,An)` includes an error identifier on the
>   exception and displays a formatted error message.

Since you have access to the scripts being run, you can update them to include verbose error messages.

For example:

```
>> assert((2+2) == 5)
Assertion failed.
```

vs.

```
>> assert((2+2) == 5, 'The rules of The Universe still hold')
Some rules of The Universe still hold
```

Comment: Well, it's gonna be annoying going through and annotating all of my asserts, but this is a good workaround.  Thanks!